# Pandas: getting the name of the minimum column with timedelta datatype

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I will use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188151/pandas-getting-the-name-of-the-minimum-column/73346957#73346957) minimal reproducible example except I will have [Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html) scalars instead of integers and `np.NAN` values.

I'm also trying to solve the same problem as that person tried to solve. For each row, I want the name of the minimum column. All of that, in a fourth column of the same dataframe.

Here is how to reproduce the error:

```
incomplete_df = pd.DataFrame({'event1': [pd.Timedelta("1 days"),    pd.Timedelta("2 days"), pd.Timedelta("nat"),    pd.Timedelta("5 days") ,    pd.Timedelta("6 days"), pd.Timedelta("nat"),    pd.Timedelta("nat"),    pd.Timedelta("11 days"),    pd.Timedelta("nat"),    pd.Timedelta("15 days")],   
                              'event2': [pd.Timedelta("nat"),   pd.Timedelta("1 days") ,    pd.Timedelta("nat"),    pd.Timedelta("3 days") ,    pd.Timedelta("4 days"), pd.Timedelta("7 days") ,    pd.Timedelta("nat"),    pd.Timedelta("12 days"),    pd.Timedelta("nat"),    pd.Timedelta("17 days")],   
                              'event3': [pd.Timedelta("nat"),   pd.Timedelta("nat"),    pd.Timedelta("nat"),    pd.Timedelta("nat"),    pd.Timedelta("6 days"), pd.Timedelta("4 days") ,    pd.Timedelta("9 days") ,    pd.Timedelta("nat"),    pd.Timedelta("3 days") ,    pd.Timedelta("nat")]})
```

And then running:

```
incomplete_df['reason'] = "Reason is " + incomplete_df.idxmin(axis="columns")
```

will throw the following error:

```
ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence
```

The thing I did to avoid the error is to first convert the data to integers and `np.NAN` values. This is however probably not how it should be done. Any idea, why this doesn't work with timedeltas even though there is a pretty obvious way of picking the minimum of several timedelta objects?

EDIT: I'm using `Python 3.9.10`

EDIT2: an issue has been created about this [inconsistency](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/48123).

Comment: Third row (index 2) is `NaT` only. `.idxmin(axis=1)` can't handle that. `incomplete_df.drop(2).idxmin(axis="columns")` should work.

Comment: If you can't avoid it, try `incomplete_df['reason'] = "Reason is " + incomplete_df[incomplete_df.notna().any(axis=1)].idxmin(axis=1)`.

Comment: @Timus it can handle it with integers though. I don't understand why it doesn't with NaT (I just tried removing the second row, it does solve the problem but with integers I didn't need to do that first)

Comment: The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) say: _Raises ValueError if the row/column is empty_. But you are right, it works with integers. I tried to find why that's the case in the [Pandas source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L10157) but got lost (a bit of a rabbit hole).

Comment: I guess I need to make an issue then, tried to read the source code as well but ngl my two years of Python aren't enough to see clear enough in that

Comment: Seems like a good idea. +1